# Getting error when trying to get a Variable from another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I am making a discord bot to where my friends can get a random meme when they type a command. The variable I am using is in a different file called `./translate`. When I try to use the variable, my bot crashes.

Here is the code from the `./translate`

```
module.exports.meme = [
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/60f7fcb2f6005a86d191fdc92c54ce4875bbc4003dcc689586757be212e8653d_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/6d3565cf992d951ebf62c6f8c313ebf2949ef4baafa6bbf6fc97cacb0e998df1_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/bea43e9848048bcf2bf4a646c410993d7800a6eeb69cea7ef8f0da6d5d098908_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/e126e4e9fa73e4ada39f85e29da7d443d752cd75fca5bff6b9596ca6248022c7_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/13a7b2a4b26e6f6dead5d35c4d147c346a363977c75c6105e25ca470fc77ec00_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/2aad4679f43b7acdf1d40b3ba0c48fe6a88fbb9233da89a91c986b83b828fa16_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/f9c74dd7410419400a6295a151da5fdecfeac06bbec666a05e7659cf40cd0627_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/8f7209128ed3265cfc4142a75504e185f203c6daf3614fa86c632307a6490270_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/939e697b8b2cea141e2aea424b7c985946395f8b99e4b21170566221ee804009_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/7a4517f2966d15a4abb79662e006002c667c6d0a68d804d01a75ef5ace034613_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/0801a830eac2622572a683783f13525fca19e3b0f5fc74058ce11e08ffc3a012_1.jpg",
];
```

Here is the code that is trying to receive the variable:

```
var sourceFile = require('./translate');


function randMeme() {
    console.log(sourceFile.meme);
    return  meme[Math.floor(Math.random()*meme.length)];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function randMeme() {
    console.log(sourceFile.meme);
    return meme[Math.floor(Math.random()*meme.length)];
           ^^^^                          ^^^^
}
```

Try adding `var meme = sourceFile.meme;` before referencing `meme`.

**Alternatively, you could rewrite your two files as such:**

```
/* translate.js */
module.exports = [
    "http://...",
    ...
];
```

```
/* main file */
var meme = require('./translate');

function randMeme() {
    console.log(meme);
    return meme[Math.floor(Math.random()*meme.length)];
}
```

Notice I removed `.meme` from `module.exports.meme` here.

Answer (score 0):

variable 'sourceFile' will have structure like this

```
{
  meme: [
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/60f7fcb2f6005a86d191fdc92c54ce4875bbc4003dcc689586757be212e8653d_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/6d3565cf992d951ebf62c6f8c313ebf2949ef4baafa6bbf6fc97cacb0e998df1_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/bea43e9848048bcf2bf4a646c410993d7800a6eeb69cea7ef8f0da6d5d098908_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/e126e4e9fa73e4ada39f85e29da7d443d752cd75fca5bff6b9596ca6248022c7_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/13a7b2a4b26e6f6dead5d35c4d147c346a363977c75c6105e25ca470fc77ec00_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/2aad4679f43b7acdf1d40b3ba0c48fe6a88fbb9233da89a91c986b83b828fa16_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/f9c74dd7410419400a6295a151da5fdecfeac06bbec666a05e7659cf40cd0627_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/8f7209128ed3265cfc4142a75504e185f203c6daf3614fa86c632307a6490270_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/939e697b8b2cea141e2aea424b7c985946395f8b99e4b21170566221ee804009_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/7a4517f2966d15a4abb79662e006002c667c6d0a68d804d01a75ef5ace034613_1.jpg",
    "http://img.ifcdn.com/images/0801a830eac2622572a683783f13525fca19e3b0f5fc74058ce11e08ffc3a012_1.jpg"
  ]
}
```

In your randMeme function, there is an incorrect syntax (node does not know variable 'meme'.

Please change like this (use sourceFile.meme instead of meme)

```
function randMeme() {
    console.log(sourceFile.meme);
    return  sourceFile.meme[Math.floor(Math.random() * sourceFile.meme.length)];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add the file extension like `translate.js`

Comment: `require()` does not need the file extension in order to import the module. And even if the file doesn't have an extension it would still work anyway.